# Integration between Codeigniter and Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

i'm developing a website. I would like to use Wordpress to create homepage and other pages, and Codeigniter to create other. What is the best way to do this?
So, for example:

```
http://mysitename.com/ => Go to WORDPRESS Homepage.
http://mysitename.com/animals/cat => Call the cat function in animals controller in CODEIGNITER.
http://mysitename.com/contact => Go to WORDPRESS Contact page.
```

How could i realize that? Is it possible?
For example, could i show Wordpress page using it as view in Codeigniter Controller?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do the two applications need to share data, design, etc. ?? Is it an Apache server?

Comment: Check this http://ci-wp.com/

Comment: I'm curious how slow this is going to be. WordPress by itself is pretty slow, and codeigniter is right up there with some of the slower frameworks by requests. Why don't you just develop in WordPress?

Comment: Thank you for answer.. would be nice if in codeigniter pages i could use header and footer of wordpress homepage. Yes, it is an Apache server. No other data need to be shared. Login is not required. #Alex i don't know if it will be slow, the codeigniter pages i've is quite fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create wordpress as primary :

**Add the WordPress index File**

```
require_once('/Server/path/to/wp-load.php');
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

**Extend Codeigniter URL Helper**

create a new namespaced function to ‘extend’ the URL helper of CodeIgniter. By using ci_site_url, we can resolve the site_url issue. The My_url_helper.php (helper) file should be in the application directory of CodeIgniter.

**Change site_url to ci_site_url in CodeIgniter App**

Quick search your applications, controllers, models, and directories and replace all site_url file references with ci_site_url.

**WordPress stopping Contorting from Cookies**

CodeIgniter will create cookies for every active database session when you log in. This can lead to WordPress bootstrap file rectifying the issue. This happens when WordPress loops via the $_COOKIE global and implements add_magic_quotes functionality to all elements. In line no. apprx 520

```
function ci_ignore_magic_quotes($value,$key)
{
    if($key != "ci_session")
    {
        stripslashes_deep($value);
    }
}

Comment out the following lines inside the wp_magic_quotes function and add a reference to the ci_ignore_magic_quotes function.
array_walk($_COOKIE, 'ci_ignore_magic_quotes');
//$_COOKIE = add_magic_quotes( $_COOKIE );
Additionally, you will have to set WordPress to not unset the $_COOKIE['ci_session']:
$no_unset = array( 'GLOBALS', '_GET', '_POST', '_COOKIE', '_REQUEST', \\
 '_SERVER', '_ENV', '_FILES', 'table_prefix','ci_session' );
```

you can start using WordPress with your CodeIgniter application like as usually in use.

More Tutorials :
https://gist.github.com/philbirnie/4674643

https://www.cometchat.com/blog/how-to-integrate-codeigniter-with-wordpress/

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer! I've done all, but how can i decide when an url should be used with Codeigniter or with Wordpress?
For example, i want to show the homepage of WP at this url:
http://mysitename.com but, obviously, now i get the index function of main CI Controller. To show the homepage of WP i have to go at url:
http://mysitename.com/wordpress (my WP directory). How can i solve?

Comment: In other words, how can i show WP pages without writing subdirectory in url?

Comment: Wordpress menu have facility for custom link.For pages writing go to admin > dashboard > settings > Permalinks